# Error while using Lucene with H2 Database

Tags: java, database, lucene, h2

I want to implement a small fullText search in my project that uses H2 Database (embedded). As I know I have to use Lucene for fullText engine for find relevance results (not only containing results).
But I can't use it. This block is Lucene initiation:

```
FullTextLucene.init(connection);
FullTextLucene.createIndex(connection, "PUBLIC", Tables.COURSES_DETAIL, Columns.NAME);
```

Also I used this way:

```
  stmt.execute(
      "create alias if not exists FTL_INIT for \"org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene.init\"");
  stmt.execute("call FTL_INIT()");
  stmt.execute(
      String.format("CALL FTL_CREATE_INDEX('PUBLIC','%s',%s)", Tables.COURSES_DETAIL, "NULL"));
```

But this error happens at runtime:

```
Error creating or initializing trigger "FTL_COURSES_DETAIL" object, class "org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene$FullTextTrigger", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Class ""org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene$FullTextTrigger"" not found [90086-197]"; see root cause for details; SQL statement:
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS "PUBLIC"."FTL_COURSES_DETAIL" AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ROLLBACK ON "PUBLIC"."COURSES_DETAIL" FOR EACH ROW CALL "org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene$FullTextTrigger"
```

After I downgraded H2 library to latest 'stable' version (1.4.196) the error has been changed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory;
```

and sometimes this error:

```
Exception calling user-defined function: "init(conn1: url=jdbc:default:connection user=INFC): org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory;"; SQL statement:
call FTL_INIT()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. But I know this isn't best one.

I downgraded Lucene lib to 3.6.2 and used plain queries instead of `FullTextLucene` functions.